# matplot avline dates wrong position

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot error by date (this is measured weekly) and add some vertical lines for particular dates. My data looks like:

[image]

I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pylt
pylt.xticks(rotation=90)
pylt.plot_date(det.dia_corte_fin_prediccion, det.avg_error_diario_semana, fmt='o', 
               tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False)

fechas=list(det['fecha_baja'].unique())
fechas=[x for x in fechas if str(x) != 'nan']
for i in fechas:
    pylt.axvline(i, color='black')# esta fecha deberia ser unica



fechas=list(det['fec_ultima_fecha_creacion_sol_baja_anterior'].unique())
fechas.extend( list(det['fec_primera_fecha_creacion_sol_baja_posterior'].unique()))
fechas=[x for x in fechas if str(x) != 'nan']

for i in fechas:
    pylt.axvline(i, color='blue',zorder=0)
```

But I get a graph with the vertical lines in an incorrect position:

[image]

I also chaged the type of column to datetime and I still get the same problem:

```
columnas=det.filter(like='fec', axis=1).columns

for i in columnas:
    det[i]=pd.to_datetime(det[i])
```

The problem is that if the date is not on the axis it will plot it at the end.

So now I need to create all the dates in the axis to avoid this problem. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that the correct way is to change the type of plot to scatter:
That way it will add dates in the correct place and if needed between the original dates provided and not at the end.

```
det.dia_corte_fin_prediccion=pd.to_datetime(det.dia_corte_fin_prediccion)
ax=pylt.scatter(det.dia_corte_fin_prediccion, det.avg_error_diario_semana)
pylt.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2019-08-06'), color='green')
pylt.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2019-08-11'), color='green')
```